# Why can't I get a 5.3.3 libphp.so?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ubuntu, php

I am on an ubuntu 10.04 system and I am building php 5.3.3. I can build a CGI version just fine,  but when i try and build a .so with this command:

`./configure  --with-apxs2=/usr/bin/apxs2 --enable-so --disable-cgi`

I get this:

```
Notice: Following unknown configure options were used:

--enable-so
```

So how do I build a .so with 5.3.3?

Comment: have update my answer and it indeeds does not require the --enable-so anymore nor have it on the configure options as i stated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the below command you will see all available command for compiling it:

```
./configure --help |less
```

While i was browsing it i saw no --enable-so anymore so i am assuming that only using `--with-apxs2=path/apsx2` will do the job for you.

I will be compiling this in a minute and let you know how it goes.

**UPDATE:**

I have just finished compiling the version 5.3.3 and it indeed **DONT NEED OR HAVE** the `--enable-so` aslong as you specify the `--with-apxs2`

I have configured it with:

> ./configure --prefix=/usr
>   --enable-sockets --enable-bcmath --with-pear=/usr/lib/pear --with-mysql=/usr --enable-calendar --with-mhash=/usr --with-kerberos --with-config-file-path=/etc --with-gd --with-xsl --with-freetype-dir=/usr --enable-exif --with-jpeg-dir=/usr --with-png-dir=/usr --with-zlib-dir=/usr --with-pdo-mysql --enable-ftp --with-curl=/usr --with-pspell=/usr --enable-mbstring --with-mcrypt --with-mysqli --with-openssl=/usr --with-gettext --enable-pcntl --with-apxs2
>   && make && make install

Once the proccess was done there was a `/usr/lib/httpd/modules/libphp5.so` in place.

Also during the compilation you can see the below:

```
Installing PHP SAPI module:       apache2handler
/usr/lib/httpd/build/instdso.sh SH_LIBTOOL='/usr/lib/apr-1.3.9/build-1/libtool' libphp5.la /usr/lib/httpd/modules
/usr/lib/apr-1.3.9/build-1/libtool --mode=install cp libphp5.la /usr/lib/httpd/modules/
cp .libs/libphp5.so /usr/lib/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
cp .libs/libphp5.lai /usr/lib/httpd/modules/libphp5.la
```

it has also included the `LoadModule php5_module lib/httpd/modules/libphp5.so` on my httpd.conf automaticly without the need to do it by hand.

Comment: Yeah i have that in my ./configure and i'm not getting a .so file. `find . | grep "\.so"` doesn't find anything :(

Comment: @Rook are you sure your ./configure on 5.3.3 display the --enable-so option ? it is from what i know default options when you type it.

Comment: I have totally used the `--enable-so` option before.  I just grabbed the latest 5.3.3 source from php.net and its not there,  i even tried grepping though the -h looking or `.so`,  so such luck.  There is a php-cgi option, but i don't want that.

Comment: I am not questionning the existence of --enable-so in the past version all i am saying is that the new version does not have it on the configure options. When i said that i was looking at the configure of 5.3.3 as i was installing it. **i have just set it to compile and i will tell you soon about the .so**

Answer (score 2):

http://nexlinux.blogspot.com/ 
I've write the way i compiled php 5.3.3. May be the above could help you..

Comment: Thanks,  but i don't want to use php-cgi.  i want a libphp5.so.

Comment: You can skip php-cgi

Comment: yeah but i'm not getting a .so! thats the whole point of this post.